# How to generate unique id for each user at time of registration in react native?

Tags: react-native

For identifying each user i am trying to generate unique id at the time of registration in react native.How is it possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: Will the ID be displayed to the user? Is this just a database ID? Will this ID be used in the URL to link to a user profile?

Comment: No this ID will not be displayed to the user.I want this ID to be set as session.So that each time i can check whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: When user registration call API and generate unique id on server after successful registration return unique id to app and save it

Comment: So how do i generate unique id at registration?

Comment: reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

the best way is using an UUID generator.
to install UUID generator use the two following cammands

```
$ npm install react-native-uuid-generator --save

$ react-native link react-native-uuid-generator
```

then import from 'react-native-uuid-generator'

```
import UUIDGenerator from 'react-native-uuid-generator';
```

for reference click [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-uuid-generator)

Comment: what version of UUID does this library generate?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timestamp for every user as id, but uuid is the best solution.